# Arc length of an irregular curve in Python

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm trying to find arc length of a vessel by choosing two points on it.

The function `cv.ArcLength()` raises the following exception:

```
TypeError: All elements of sequence 'curve' must be same size
```

Here is my code:

```
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
adist=cv.ArcLength(contours,(x1,x2), isClosed=-1)
```

The values of the variables `x1` and `x2` were obtained from a mouse event.

Does anyone know the solution? Is it possible to find the arc length by integration on an irregular curve?

Comment: what do you need the (x,y) point for ? it will get interpreted as a slice(no idea what that is for..)     you could try `cv2.ArcLength(contours,isClosed=-1)`    also, it seems to me, that mixing cv and cv2 (old vs new api ) is never a good idea

Comment: contours is a list of contours, right ? i think arclength works on a single contour only. so something like contours[0]

Comment: Arc length calculation is part of another parameter calculation.And I want to calculate arc length of particular portion vessel which can be selected by a mouse event. To specify the end points I gave the variables x1 and x2. @berak Thank you for your quick response.